# How to check if a checkbox is checked using *jquery mmenu plugin*

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, mmenu

Hi :) a subject very explanatory I guess. I know this question was asked before, but none of the proposed solutions worked with the **mmenu plugin**.

Here is the link to use checkbox:
http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/addons/toggles.html

I used both ways to verify if a checkbox was checked:

**HTML**
//bicisenda is the input id.

```
<input id="bicisenda" type="checkbox" name="poi" value="Bicisenda" class="Toggle">
```

**JS/JQuery**

```
$('ul li ul li #bicisenda').click(function() {
  var _checked = $("#bicisenda").is(":checked"); 
  if (_checked) {
    console.log("Checked");    
  }

});
```

The author'splugin suggested me to try the code below:

```
$('#bicisenda').change(function() {
  var _checked = $("#bicisenda").is(":checked"); 
  if (_checked) {
    console.log("Checked");    
  }
});
```

His explanation was that with this add-on the input is hidden, so I see a label that is linked to the input. Summed it up, I don't click the input.
However his suggestion didn't work either.

Any ideas how to check if a checkbox (or radiobutton) is checked?, thanks so much in advance

Comment: What type of html element is actually changing?

Comment: Visually the checkbox, actually I can't figure it out since the checkbox is wrapped within a label.

Answer (score 0):

Well after digging deeper with the plugin code, I finally get it working.

The solution was the following

**HTML**

```
<input id="bicisenda" type="checkbox" name="bic" value="Bicisenda" class="Toggle">
```

**JQuery**

I made a function that is called in the html code.

```
function bicis() {
  var $bicisendas    = $('input[name="bic"');
  $bicisendas.click(function() {
      if ($bicisendas.is( ':checked' ))
      {

        console.log("Checked");    

      }  
  });
}
```

I store the input jquery object in the variable $bicisendas and then I check the checked property when the click event occurs. I couldn't check for the property straightforwardly because the check button was wrapped by a label. I needed to isolate the element in that way to rid of the wrapper. 
This is my reasoning but being me a js/html5 newcomer any more elaborated explanations or solution are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('ul li  label span #bicisenda').click(function() {
if(this.checked) {
    console.log("Checked");
    alert("checked");
} else {
    console.log("UnChecked");
    alert("Un Checked");
}
});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {visibility: hidden;position: absolute}
label {padding: 20px;cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
<li> 
<label><span> <!--img src="imagenes/bird1.png" /--><a href="#pi/Bicesendas">Bicisendas
<input id="bicisenda" type="checkbox" name="poi" value="Bicisenda" class="Toggle"></a>
</span>
</label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Maybe in your case it works because the input is isolated of a nav menu.  In my case there are more elements:

`<li>
         <span>
                   <a href="#pi/Bicesendas">Bicisendas</a>
                   <input id="bicisenda" type="checkbox" name="bic" value="Bicisenda" class="Toggle">
                   </span>                  
                 </li>`

As I said before the author of the plugin told me the input is hidden within a label. I appreciate your help anyway :)

Comment: I realize your example isn't using the jquery mmenu plugin (as I stated in the subject), which is the one that causes the problem. If I do a regular checkbox there isn't problem at all, but this is no the problem I have.
Here is the link to the jquery mmenu plugin:
http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/download.html 
If you did a try I suggest to add the .css file also.

Comment: ps: the edited code didn't work either using jquery mmenu plugin